# What is the best way to replace text in json?

Tags: javascript, json

So I have a bunch of `JSON` data and it contains a few fields. for example:

```
[{
    "id": "XXX",
    "version": 1,
    "head": {
        "text": "Main title",
        "sub": {
            "value": "next"
        },
        "place": "secondary"
    },
    "body": [{
            "id": "XXX1",
            "info": "three little birds",
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "song",
                    "type": {
                        "value": "a"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "XXX2",
            "info": [
                "how are you?"
            ],
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "just",
                    "non-type": {
                        "value": "abc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

1. what I'm trying to do is kind of conversion table (from a different JSON file)
   if a field has the value 'a' replace it with 'some other text..' etc.
2. I have a service for the `JSON` pipeline, so I guess this is the right place to do the replacement.

so for this example, I have the `JSON` above and in my conversion table I have the following terms:

next: forward,
song: music,
a: option1,
just: from
etc...

Comment: easier to change text in an object than in a complex JSON string - so, JSON.parse it first, make the changes, JSON.stringify to get back to JSON

Comment: If these values could exist anywhere in the overall tree of objects then I suppose some sort of recursive function would be in order here.  Take the top-level object, check if it's an array, if so loop through its elements and recursively call on each, if not loop through its properties and check if each one is a value being replaced.  If it is, replace it, if it isn't, recursively call on that property.  Maybe throw in some checks for other literal types, etc. for cleanliness.

Comment: [`JSON`](http://json.org) does not contain fields. JSON is a text representation of some data structure. You have to restore the data structure using the JSON representation, change the data then encode it as JSON again.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for can be achieved with templates. Replace the variable sections with some specific markers that you can find and replace from some external tools such as `perl` or `sed`.

For example, you could have a `template.json` with something like this:

```
...
"type": {
  "value": "@@VALUE@@"
}
...
```

Then when you need the actual JSON, you could pass this though an intermediate script that replaces these templates with actual data.

```
cat template.json | sed -e 's/@@VALUE@@/my_value/' > target.json
```

Alternatively, with Perl:

```
cat template.json | perl -pi -e 's:\@\@VALUE\@\@:my_value:' > target.json
```

Comment: It's in an Angular project

Comment: Your question sure doesn't mention Angular, and you mention JSON files implying file manipulation. If its not rendered JSON file manipulation, question doesn't make any sense as you could just make the desired changes on the parsed object directly and then serialize it again.

Comment: Perfect . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to parse it, replace the text in the object, and then stringify it.

The next best way is to use a regular expression.

In this example, I catch exceptions if path cannot be indexed, and use `['type']` instead of `.type` so it will scale to indexing `'non-type'` if you wish.

```js
const data = `[{
    "id": "XXX",
    "version": 1,
    "head": {
        "text": "Main title",
        "sub": {
            "value": "next"
        },
        "place": "secondary"
    },
    "body": [{
            "id": "XXX1",
            "info": "three little birds",
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "song",
                    "type": {
                        "value": "a"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "XXX2",
            "info": [
                "how are you?"
            ],
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "just",
                    "non-type": {
                        "value": "abc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}]
`

const o = JSON.parse(data)
o[0].body.forEach(b => {
  try {
    if (b.extended.spl['type'].value === 'a') {
      b.extended.spl['type'].value = 'CHANGED'
    }
  } catch (e) {}
})

const newData = JSON.stringify(o, null, 2)
console.log(newData)
```

A string replace approach will work if you know and can rely on your source conforming, such as the only `"value"` is inside `"type"`

```js
const data = `[{
    "id": "XXX",
    "version": 1,
    "head": {
        "text": "Main title",
        "sub": {
            "value": "next"
        },
        "place": "secondary"
    },
    "body": [{
            "id": "XXX1",
            "info": "three little birds",
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "song",
                    "type": {
                        "value": "a"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "XXX2",
            "info": [
                "how are you?"
            ],
            "extended": {
                "spl": {
                    "text": "just",
                    "non-type": {
                        "value": "abc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}]
`

const newData = data.replace(/"value": "a"/g, '"value": "NEWVALUE"')

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Ok, Can you give an example?